# Facebook Graph API - How to get scheduler post's all detail in graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in facebook graph API, I want to get all the details of scheduler post like

- `full_picture`
- `message`
- etc

I used :

```
GET v4.0/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_ScheduledPost} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

But, I got error :

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "A-aQAYXFbAdSX7oMYfcUP_3"
     }
}
```

Ref., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/scheduled-post/

Comment: can you identify the exact field that produces the error? use just one for testing.

Comment: @luschn I used this API GET `https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/...?fields={id}&access_token=<page_access_token>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets and dots are just placeholders.

**Wrong**

```
fields={id,message,...}
```

**Correct**

```
fields=id,message,...
```

**Also, you have to use the ID of a scheduled post instead of just using "..." in the API call.**

---

To get all scheduled posts, use this endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/scheduled_posts/

Example:

```
/me/scheduled_posts?fields=id,message&access_token=<your-page-token>
```

Comment: Again, I got the same error `(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...`. API URL is right?

Comment: and you really just tried with with "fields=id&access_token=..."? please comment your exact api call (without the token, of course)

Comment: Please, can you write full API?

Comment: My API is GET `https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/...?fields=id,message&access_token=<page_access_token>`

Comment: that cannot be the exact api call....you are not using "...", right? ;)

Comment: I'm using `'...'`

Comment: ...why would you do that? you are basically not using any api endpoint. of course you have to replace this with the id of a scheduled post...

Comment: now i get it, the error message actually tells you that "..." does not exist, it´s not even about fields. yeah, of course that´s the problem.

Comment: I want to get a page's all scheduler list.

Comment: i have added that to my answer

Comment: I can't get group post detail by `https://graph.facebook.com/<group_id>/feed?access_token=<user_access_token>`. Please, can you give a proper solution?

Comment: do you manage the group? does the user token have the correct permissions authorized? what exactly does not work? do you get posts, but not with details? in that case, use the fields parameter.

Comment: No, I get the response `{
    "data": []
}` . User permission like `manage_pages,pages_show_list,publish_pages,business_management,publish_to_groups,groups_access_member_info,public_profile`

Comment: I have added 2 test user, One user is an admin of the group, but he can't get the group's content. How can I get? I have one another solution That add our app in a group setting and get the data, but I don't show my app in setting (because of app is in development mode). Please, Can you explain how to get the group post list?